# Find OS number of updates available

Tags: bash

Is there a way to find the number of update's available for the *nix operating system?

Where I got the idea? Byobu let regular user know the number of updates available.

Using yum check-updates can inform regular-user about updates but in Debian apt-get or aptitude cannot be called by regular-user.
How does byobu get the info, is there an bash command for this?

Comment: This is specific to each operating system, and is independent of `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `update-notifier-common` installed, it is as simple as:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check 2>&1 | awk '-F;' 'END { print $1, $2 }'
```

How'd I know? I copied from the Byobu source. [You should check out the full implementation](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~kirkland/byobu/trunk/view/head:/usr/lib/byobu/updates_available#L41), as it is quite straightforward and has cases for all the common package managers.

For reference, here is a copy of the commands Byobu uses to support the other package managers:

#### apt-get

(without relying on `update-notifier-common`)

```
apt-get -s -o Debug::NoLocking=true upgrade | grep -c ^Inst
```

#### packagekit

```
pkcon get-updates -p | awk '
/^Results:$/ { start=NR }
/^Security/ { security++ }
END {
    if (!/There are no updates available at this time./) {
        print NR-start, security
    }
}'
```

#### zypper

```
zypper --no-refresh lu --best-effort | grep -c 'v |'
```

#### yum

```
yum list updates -q | grep -vc "Updated Packages"
```

#### pacman

```
pacman -Sup | grep -vc "^\(::\| \)"
```

#### homebrew

```
brew outdated | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to run `apticron` or a similar utility.  `apticron` runs as cronjob utility and updates the package index (`apt-get update`) and emails to you a list of available packages updates and their priority level.

Also, a regular user can use `apt-get` with the `-s` (simulation option).  For example:

```
apt-get -s upgrade
```

This shows what would upgrade would do without actually doing it.  So, if upgrades are available in the current package list, this shows what they are.

Of course, if your regular user has full `sudo` permissions, then he can run `apt-get` just as root would.